# Adding Lightning Pages to Managed Packages

Tags: lightning-aura-components, flexipages

I have some Lightning Pages in my managed package which are linked to from some Lightning Components. They don't have their own tabs.

When I have deployed them to a new scratch org, I've had to activate each one. How can I make it so that the pages are activated automatically when someone installs the package? Or will that just happen?